# solr error null:java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I have setup Solr 7.4 cluster with 2 nodes and 1 replica and one collection with 30 shards (Because I want to transfer 10 TB of the documents from Hbase to Solr)
[image]

When I add the documents(Multi-threaded with 20 threads), I will encounter this error :

```
null:java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$ErrorState.noContent(HttpInput.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:313)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletInputStreamWrapper.read(ServletInputStreamWrapper.java:74)
at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastInputStream.readWrappedStream(FastInputStream.java:79)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastInputStream.refill(FastInputStream.java:88)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastInputStream.peek(FastInputStream.java:60)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:107)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 120001/120000 ms
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput failure
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.failed(HttpInput.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$BlockingReadCallback.failed(HttpConnection.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:406)
    ... 9 more
```

#### Update

I have **60GB** of Ram with **15GB** heap size for per Server.
[image]

Comment: Please check your GC and threads waiting then accordingly tune the memory. You also mentioned replica but I didn't see any. Also could you bit explain how much data is that for which you might be needing these 30 shards

Comment: @AmanTandon thanks for the answer.  I updated the question. I chose 30 Shards for this collection Because I want to transfer 10 TB of the documents from Hbase to Solr,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?